# Ubuntu fails to start with ACPI errors

Tags: boot, networking, nvidia, acpi

I have a problem starting Ubuntu, which I don't how to solve. It's difficult for me to describe my problem exactly, because I'm new in the Linux world, so I posted a picture of the problem:

[image: picture for the problem]

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved.
The solve :
Step 1:
when you get this screen :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF2Ni.jpg
Press key 'e'
Step 2 :
You will get screen after step 1
From this screen move the pointer to line starts with linux word in last this  line add acpi=off then press ctrl+x . After that your ubuntu will start.
step 3:
After start ubuntu open the terminal and  write this commands
Command 1:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then add acpi=off like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYP4G.jpg
Then save . 
After that from the terminal write this comand .
Command 2:

```
sudo update-grub
```

The end.